# identifying and extracting the prior observation for a specific source

Tags: r

i have a data in the form:

```
id   source
1    m
1    p
1    l1
1    l1
2    t
2    q
3    p
3    l1
3    n
3    l1
```

Now for every id, i want to identify l1 when it occurs in the source and extract the observation prior to l1.
For eg: for id 1, the 3rd source in l1 and the observation prior to that is p.
so my data should look like this:

```
id    source
1      p
3      p
3      n
```

How can i create this in R?

Comment: Can you clarify the expected behavior for the second "l1" value with id of 1 (i.e. row 4)?  The observation prior to that one would also be "l1".  It's not clear if you only care about the first instance of "l1" for a given id (in which case you should be careful about ordering), or if you do care about all of them and you want to retrieve the first prior observation that wasn't also "l1" but you only want unique combinations of id and prior source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more direct method, but try this:

```
#get your data
test <- read.table(text="id   source
1    m
1    p
1    l1
1    l1
2    t
2    q
3    p
3    l1
3    n
3    l1",header=TRUE)

# do some picking of the cases
result <- do.call(rbind,by(test,test$id,function(x) x[which(x$source=="l1")-1,]))
result <- result[result$source!="l1",]
```

Which gives:

```
> result
  id source
2  1      p
7  3      p
9  3      n
```

Comment: Thanks this works!! I'm very new to R and have just started working on it. I had tried the lag function but it was more for time series so it did'nt work on my data.

Answer (score 3):

A data.table solution

```
 library(data.table)

 dd <- data.table(df)
 dd[, source[match('l1', source)-1L],by = id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another data.table solution.  I wasn't able to get what seemed like a correct answer with the earlier version from @mnel.

```
library(data.table)

## Create the test data table:
dt <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 source1=c("m","p","l1","l1","t","q","p","l1","n","l1"))

dt[,list(id, source1, source0=c(NA,source1[seq_len(.N-1L)]))][source1=="l1"]

##    id source1 source0
## 1:  1      l1       p
## 2:  1      l1      l1
## 3:  3      l1       p
## 4:  3      l1       n
```

This is adding a column source0 to the data table that gets the previous row (or NA for the first row).  The `.N` is a row number, and I'm using `seq_len` to get the previous row number.  Then it subsets the result where the original source1 has a value of "l1".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized solution using only simple functions from the base of R.

If `DF` is the input data frame then `sel` is a logical vector whose `TRUE` components select out the required rows.   The three terms connected by `&` signs select those rows:

- for which the following row's `source` column equals "l1" and
- whose source column is not `l1` and
- are such that the following row is not the first with that `id`

The length of `sel` is one less than the number of rows in `DF` so we use `which` to avoid recycling of `sel`.

```
is.l1 <- DF$source == "l1"
sel <- is.l1[-1] & !is.l1[-nrow(DF)] & duplicated(DF$id)[-1]
DF[which(sel),]
```

The result of the last line is:

```
  id source
2  1      p
7  3      p
9  3      n
```